# How to set Payment Source in Spree for new Payment Settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, spree

I'm trying to configure a new Payment Setting (EFT) in Rails 5.2 and Spree 3.7.4 app. Here is what my spree admin section for payment settings looks like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3XE.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3XE.png): My localhost admin/payment_methods/ https://i.stack.imgur.com/03QSS.png

And i have also setup the config/initializers/spree.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Configure Spree Preferences
#
# Note: Initializing preferences available within the Admin will overwrite any changes that were made
#         through the user interface when you restart.
#       If you would like users to be able to update a setting with the Admin it should NOT be set here.
#
# Note: If a preference is set here it will be stored within the cache & database upon initialization.
#       Just removing an entry from this initializer will not make the preference value go away.
#       Instead you must either set a new value or remove entry, clear cache, and remove database entry.
#
# In order to initialize a setting do:
# config.setting_name = 'new value'
Spree.config do |config|
  config.tax_using_ship_address = false
  config.require_master_price = false
end

# Configure Spree Dependencies
#
# Note: If a dependency is set here it will NOT be stored within the cache & database upon initialization.
#       Just removing an entry from this initializer will make the dependency value go away.
#
Spree.dependencies do |dependencies|
  # Example:
  # Uncomment to change the default Service handling adding Items to Cart
  # dependencies.cart_add_item_service = 'MyNewAwesomeService'
end

Spree.user_class = 'Spree::User'

Rails.application.config.spree.payment_methods << Spree::Gateway::GooglePay
Rails.application.config.spree.payment_methods << Spree::Gateway::Eft
```

When i try to checkout via EFT on my local, i get a "{:"payments.source"=>["can't be blank"]}".. please see screenshot [payments.source locahost error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX3XE.png)

How to set the payment source in new Spree payment Gateways?